# Close (not kill) process by pid python

Tags: python, process

I'm Creating a program to automatically restart some software I'm using. However closing the process using taskkill causes loss of saved data. However right clicking the process on the taskbar and closing it keeps the data.

Is there a way in python to do this without needing to control the mouse?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Did you try to research and read documentation, in order to understand *what actually happens* when you right-click -> close?

Comment: That is a good idea, I'm using windows.
I'll try to research what happens when a window is closed

Comment: Do you use `taskkill /f`? According to [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/959364/on-windows-how-can-i-gracefully-ask-a-running-program-to-terminate), removing the `/f` flag should terminate the process gracefully.

Comment: yes that worked Andre